# CCRenderTexture saveToFile takes up a large amount of memory

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on a game and I want to create thumbnails of each level so I can use them in a menu.  I do this with CCRenderTexture like this:

```
CCRenderTexture *renderer = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:bounds.size.width height:bounds.size.height];
ScreenShotLayer *scene = [[ScreenShotLayer alloc] init];
[renderer begin];
[scene visit];
[renderer end];

[renderer saveToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%@.png", level.levelId] format: kCCImageFormatPNG];
```

This all works well and my image is saved, but it takes up a huge amount of memory and never releases it.  Without saving this data my game takes 8 MB of RAM.  When I save the image it takes over 430 MB.

If I leave everything the same and just comment out the `saveToFile` call I'm back to my 8 MB memory usage.  I've debugged this with the leaks tool and it doesn't find any leaks.

Is this a framework issue?  Is there a better way to handle this?  Am I doing something silly?

My whole game is open source and you can get it at https://github.com/zgrossbart/bridges.  This code happens in [LevelMgr.mm](https://github.com/zgrossbart/bridges/blob/master/bridges2/LevelMgr.mm).

Thanks for the help,

Zack

Comment: Have you tested this on an actual device?

Comment: Yes I have.  I see this same behavior when testing on a real iPhone 4s or my iPad 3.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem on the Cocos2d forum and with a bit of poking around the code.  You can read the forum post her:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/48890

I still see CCRenderTexture leak a little memory.  The Cocos2d team has tested this and says it's working in 2.1-beta.  There's also a big performance improvement I could have made to my code.

I was using CCRenderTexture to create a thumbnail image of a Cocos2d scene.  I did that by using CCRenderTexture to create a full size image and then using a special UIImage to resize and crop the image.  It's much more efficient to create a CCRenderTexture of the size I want in the end and scale my Cocos2d scene to the size I want in the end.